# New instance of subclassed Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, abstract-class, subclass

I have an abstract Android fragment subclass:

```
abstract class MyClass : Fragment()
```

This class will have a handful of non-abstract subclass fragments. I want each subclass to have a standard `newInstance()` method, but I'd like to define this method in the `companion object` of `MyClass`.

```
abstract class SubClass : Myclass()
val instance = SubClass.newInstance()
```

Is it possible to do this without passing a generic type to the `newInstance()` method? Can I return the correct type for the subclass?

Comment: I don't think you can inherit the static method to the subclass from the superclass's companion object. I also don't see how you intend to customize the subclass fragment argument bundle when necessary. Please expand on what you wish to accomplish.

Comment: Unless anyone else can provide a better answer, "It isn't possible" is a fine answer. Feel free to answer with that! I don't need to modify the bundle in most cases, so that isn't a huge concern in this specific use case.